# Disable computer to boot from CD or USB in windows 10 build 1809

Tags: boot, bios, bootable-media

How should I disable boot such as CD,DVD,USB in Windows 10 Build 1809. I went to BIOS but couldn't find the option to disable the Removable Drive and CD-ROM Drive

Comment: The operating system is irrelevant in that case. When booting, your OS is not yet loaded, thus have no influence on the process.
Could you provide us with information on your hardware ?
And your UEFI version ?

Comment: If Secure Boot is Enabled, Windows 10 will not boot from a DVD or USB unless it is proper Windows 10 Install media.

Comment: Even if an optical disk is used, which happens to be an image of the Windows 10 installation media, unless the boot order indicates that device should be used it won't boot to the installation media before booting to Windows 10.

Comment: @xxestter - Please provide a screenshot of the available options that do exist.  Please provide us much information as possible.  **The boot order of devices is controlled by the firmware not Windows.**